# Fetch a single LFS file from protected github repo

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have switched from dropbox + script to github LFS to store large files.
Do you know a way to fetch a file stored in LFS using a simple curl/wget command?

To give you a bit of a background. The repository contains puppet code that automates our deployments. Since our company is using preoperative software we need to store some binary packages next to our puppet repo.

We deploy to two infrastructures one with git LFS and one without. (This issue cannot be easily fixed). On the former system I'd like to simply fetch the large files manually using curl / wget.

Comment: With a quick glance at the API, yes. Read the Storage API docs: https://github.com/github/git-lfs/tree/master/docs/api#storage-api. Anyway, not a bash question.

Comment: By the way, it won't be *a* curl/wget call, because apparently you need one call to the appropriate API endpoint to retrieve the download URL, and another call to download. But it would be very easy to write a script.

Comment: I meet the same need today, did you find a simple solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to a python interpreter you can use [git-lfs-fetch.py](https://github.com/liberapay/git-lfs-fetch.py) to download the files.